# Root access not work in Android! new File("/config").listFiles() return null

Tags: java, android, root

My phone - rooted Android 4.2. Popular file managers work well with directory like "/config" or "/data". But in my program I can't observe this directories.

I use library RootTools

```
if (RootTools.isRootAvailable()) {
    if (RootTools.isAccessGiven()) {
        new File("/config").listFiles();//null
    }
}
```

I see window with confirm "get root access" and push "yes". And I add in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_SUPERUSER" />
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `if (RootTools.isAccessGiven())` ?

Comment: @Henry, it's a typo. In real code I output result of this method in log - and it null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Root access cannot be granted to a process after the process has been started, because that'd require changing the [*PID*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier) of the process. This implies that in order to use the gained root privileges you'll have to spawn a new process, like directly spawning `ls`, `cp`, `mv`, `rm` or whatever you exactly want to do.

Note though that parsing ls' output [is a bad idea™](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls).

Because you can't easily run Java code from the shell on Android, you can't easily run Java code with root privileges. If you need to run more complex code than what you can do with simple shell commands, you might want to execute a natively compiled executable (C/C++/Rust/etc.), which would be able to utilise the root privileges and have good performance and allow for more complex code.

RootTools copes with the complexity of this by providing the [`Shell`](https://github.com/Stericson/RootTools/blob/master/RootTools/src/com/stericson/RootTools/execution/Shell.java) class to easily be able to run these commands.